# How to set specific precision to BigDecimal in Java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have BigDecimal value.

```
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("100500100500.9999999").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

It prints `100500100501.00`, although I need `100500100500.99`. Is it possible to make some restriction to precision evaluating?

Comment: Did you take a look at the docs for other possible rounding modes?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the rounding mode constant `ROUND_DOWN` in `setScale`.  However, the [overloaded `setScale` method that takes a `RoudingMode` is preferred](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-).

```
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("100500100500.9999999")
    .setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Output:

```
100500100500.99
```